# ObjectOutput throws java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization, bytearrayoutputstream, notserializableexception

This is the class that's about to be serialized into a byte array.

```
public class DummyClass implements Serializable
{
    private static transient final long serialVersionUID    = -8483859843874771619L;
    public String   y;

    public DummyClass(String y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public String getY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

This is the Serialization execution test

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    byte[] bs = null;
    try
    {
        DummyClass dummyClass = new DummyClass("World I Salute you");
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(dummyClass); // <--- Throws exception here
        bs = bos.toByteArray();
    }
    finally
    {
        out.close();
        bos.close();
    }
```

and regarding the stack trace:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: tests.DummyClassTest
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at tests.DummyClassTest.dummyTest(DummyClassTest.java:109)
```

The Obvious question is what am i doing wrong?

Cheers.

**EDIT**:

The whole Class

```
public class DummyClassTest
{
    public class DummyClass implements Serializable
    {
        private static transient final long serialVersionUID    = -8483859843874771619L;
        public String   y;

        public DummyClass(String y)
        {
            this.y = y;
        }
        public String getY()
        {
            return this.y;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void dummyTest() throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = null;
        byte[] bs = null;
        try
        {
            DummyClass dummyClass = new DummyClass("World I Salute you");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(dummyClass);
            bs = bos.toByteArray();
        }
        finally
        {
            out.close();
            bos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is all the relevant code. Where is DummyClassTest defined?

Comment: You mean the `DummyClassTest` All this code is in that class. Is a JUnit test.

Comment: paste code of DummyClassTest

Comment: Is your `DummyClass` a separate class or defined within `DummyClassTest`?

Comment: You are trying to serialize a different class than DummyClass, which I supose is not serializable.

Comment: BTW exceptions are throw, not 'cast'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A non-static inner class has an implicit reference to its outer class instance. So when you serialize DummyClass, you're also serializing this implicit reference to the DummyClassTest instance owning it.

Define the DummyClass as a top-level class (non nested), or as a static inner class, and everything will work as expected.

The following:

```
public class DummyClassTest {
    public class DummyClass {
    }
}
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
public class DummyClassTest {
}

public class DummyClass {
    private DummyClassTest outerInstance;
}
```

Comment: That's the stupidest thing I've ever wrote. Thanks I forgot to test that. :)